# How to kill a thread locked by condition variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I create a thread, and I process it "recalling" (i.e. unlocking) using condition variable.

Here's the basic code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>

std::condition_variable t1_cond;

void task() {
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ mtx };

    while (true) {
        t1_cond.wait(lock);
        std::cout << "doing somethings..." << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int message;
    std::thread t1(task);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        std::cin >> message;

        t1_cond.notify_one();

    }

    // here I want to kill the t1 thread
    // t1.join() works only if I first release lock, but it seems a weird approch

    return 0;
}
```

As you see in the code, in the end I'd like to "brutally" kill the thread, even if its processing (or waiting).

How would you do this? `t1_cond.notify_one();` and use another condition variable that, if flagged, just return?

It seems a bit complex for a basic task, maybe there's some fancy way I don't know yet.

Comment: Imo, a predicate (say shutdown) should be used alongside the cv to allow for graceful termination.

Comment: You should never forcibly "kill" a thread, it could lead to resource leaks and other problems. This is why there's no such API in `std::thread`. There are ways around that, by getting the native handle and use OS-specific functions to kill it (if available), but it's not something I recommend. If you have a deadlock situation, then you need to figure out a "proper" way to solve it. Or if you just want the thread to exit then perhaps you should rethink the design or at least the implementation of the design.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how would you do in this case? `task()` is simply a thread that list in a vector a huge amount of file, from a directory. If the task start and I exit the program, it just need to stop the task and return.

Comment: One way to approach this is to have some kind of sentinel value for the type you are processing in your thread, as a way to indicate to the thread that it should shut down. For example, in case of `int` you could think of setting `message` to `-1` to indicate to the thread it should stop processing.

Comment: Killing a thread is always a bad idea and should be your last resort when everything else fails. You want memory corruption? Cuz that's how you get process memory corruption

Comment: The basic premise of hard-killing the thread is broken from inception. I'd rather fork and kill the process than half-bake something that wasn't intended as viable from the get-go. As written the *real* problem isn't finding a way to kill the thread; the real problem is finding *yourself* having to find a way to kill the thread because the thread lifetime logic was broken long before that. Take seccpur's approach. It's the right way to solve this problem (because it is no longer a problem to begin with).

Comment: Killing a thread is bad; for example if you kill a thread when it is holding a lock (heap, user or kernel) that lock will stay locked until the program is terminated.

Comment: One more thing... you suggested "...and use another condition variable..." - don't. The exit strategy can simply be more predicate state (a bool that indicates shutdown state). Don't use condition variables to convey state (which you're already doing, so that too needs a re-think); use them to *signal* *predicate state change*. You don't need another cvar for that; you can use the one you already have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments, don't do a harsh terminate on the thread. Signal it to exit and then wait for it to complete.

As an example, we can use a as global (or shared) variable between thread and main.  There are other ways to do this, but this works for example:

Declare a global variable. Let's use and atomic so we don't have to delve into a side discussion of cache coherency between threads.

```
#include <atomic>
std::atomic_bool g_exitCondition;

std::condition_variable t1_cond;
```

Change your while loop in the thread to check for the exit condition.

```
while (g_exitCondition == false) {
    t1_cond.wait(lock);
    if (g_exitCondition == false) {
        std::cout << "doing somethings..." << std::endl;
    }
}
std::cout << "Exiting thread" << std::endl;
```

And then to correctly signal the thread to exit and wait for it to complete in main:

```
    g_exitCondition = true;
    t1_cond.notify_all();
    t1.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, mostly I've I said in the main topic: "`t1_cond.notify_one();` and use another condition variable that, if flagged, just return?", but using atomic :)